# Syntax error when using query to update table in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax-error

The PHP code uses a PDO query with prepared statements to update sections of my table.

The error being received is:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 42000 
  [1] => 1064 
  [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `EditID` = 13' at line 3 
)
```

However, I am unsure of what the nature of the syntax error is.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=createyo_TestDatabase;host=localhost","createyo_james","password");
$statement=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE `Edits` SET `Rep` = :Reputation, WHERE `EditID` = :EditID");

$statement->bindValue(':Reputation', (int) trim($_GET['Reputation']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':EditID', (int) trim($_GET['EditID']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute() or die(print_r($statement->errorInfo()));

$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
print $json;
?>
```

Comment: Remove the `,`, :Reputation,

Comment: Simple typo: a comma before the where: `SET `Rep` = :Reputation, WHERE`, should be `SET `Rep` = :Reputation WHERE ...` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I really should use a proper PHP IDE in future than the simple text editor provided by my CPannel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the comma after the SET:

```
"UPDATE `Edits` SET `Rep` = :Reputation, WHERE `EditID` = :EditID"
```

should be:

```
"UPDATE `Edits` SET `Rep` = :Reputation WHERE `EditID` = :EditID"
```